# Saving session data in Rails with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session, ruby-on-rails-4

When a user exits a page, I want to save their form data for them, so I added a handler to the unload event in Javascript. I wanted to use Rails's session hashes to save this data, so I added a method in my controller to respond to the request and save passed in params.

The method receives the request fine, and the params are passed along just okily-dokily, but **none of my changes to session are persisted.** If I log the session variable from within the method (i.e. in the same AJAX request), it seems to have been filled out, but if I access it again on a new page--same user, same client--the session has been emptied.

Yes, **I've checked the authenticity token.** The params definitely include it, and I've also turned off my authenticity exceptions to check, and the problem still exists.

Is Rails saving my session nonintuitively? (I have it set to use cookies, so it should just be a cookie, right?) Is it clearing my sessions silently in the background? No errors are ever thrown during the process, but I just can't save anything to session from AJAX apparently. It works fine if I use a normal form submission, but AJAX just silently fails.